# No event notifications are being sent to the integrated app after an envelope has been corrected in DocuSign portal

Tags: docusignapi

I have a web application that sends requests to DocuSign and receives Event Notifications from DocuSign, the Event Notifications are added to the envelope in code before they are sent to DocuSign.

If an incorrect email address is provided and I correct the envelope in the web app, Event Notifications are no longer being sent to my application for that envelope

Answer (score 0):

The "Correct" operation you do from the web app is overwriting your original request to set event notifications for your app.

In order to fix this, you would have to correct the envelope from your integration as well and ensure you still provide the same information in the envelope that you did when you originally created it.

You can embed the correct view as part of your application similar to embedded sending such that the envelope is still being updated by your integration and you can keep your webhooks in tact.